# Node.js ftp put method is writing the name of the file to be uploaded to the ftp server, not the actual file

Tags: node.js, ftp

I am trying to write an app that uploads files to an ftp server in node.js using the npm module ftp.  I have a file, foo.txt, whose content is a single line: "This is a test file to upload via ftp."  My code is:

```
var Client = require("ftp");
var fs = require("fs");
var connection = require("./connections.js");

var c = new Client();

const ftpFolder = "./files/";

var fileList = [];

fs.readdir(ftpFolder, (err, files) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        files.forEach(file => {
            console.log(file);
            fileList.push(file);
        });
    }
    console.log(fileList);
});

c.on("ready", function(){
    fileList.forEach(file => {
        c.put(file, "/backups/" + file, function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(file + " was uploaded successfully!");
            }
            c.end();
        });
    });
});

// Connect to ftp site
c.connect(connection.server_ftp);
```

I see the file foo.txt on the ftp server, but when I open it the contents are: "foo.txt".  It appears to have written the name of the file to the file rather than uploading it.  Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read a directory, it gives you a list of files. It doesn't read the contents of the file, it just lists the names of the files in the dir.

You will need to use this file name to create a path to read the file from.

```
const path = require('path')
let filePath = path.join(ftpFolder, file)
let fileContents = fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    // do the upload
})
```

As a side note... While your directory reading may work, you should consider reading the directory after the connection is established. Otherwise, there is a chance you will see it fail because it's a race condition between the client connection and the directory read. You may need to read a directory with so many files that it resolves AFTER the client connects.

You could nest the callbacks, but another way to handle this is Promises. You can kick off both async methods at the same time, and handle the results when both have resolved

```
var filesPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(ftpFolder, (err, files) => {
        if(err) reject(err)
        else resolve(files)
    })
})

var connectionPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    c.on("ready", () => { resolve(c) }
    c.connect(connection.server_ftp)
})

Promise.all([filesPromise, connectionPromise], results => {
    results[0] // files
    results[1] // client
}).catch(err => {console.error(err)})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

In my case which is very similar, I put the filename instead of the full path to file in `c.put` . From your code I think it is the same.